# UIView animation artifact

Tags: animation, uiview, artifact

I am experiencing an interesting artifact that is placed over animations that are displayed under shaded views, such as the shaded background of a `UIActionSheet` or `UIAlertView`.

The pictures below show the issue.  I have seen this happen with `UIActivityInidicators` over a white background too.

I have seen the Copy/Paste popup that displays over `UITextFields` drop their arrow behind the white background of the `UITextField` too.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]